# Writing IPTC data to jpg file

Tags: java, jpeg, exif, imaging

I would like to write IPTC data, such as title, description or keywords to an jpg file, but it does not work. If i run the sample code a second jpg file is writen, but no sample data. I am using the commons imaging library from Apache:
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/

Here is the sample code:

```
TiffImageMetadata metadata = ((JpegImageMetadata)Imaging.getMetadata(new File(JPG_PATH +    
        "\\IMGP5996_empty.jpg"))).getExif();
ExifRewriter rewriter = new ExifRewriter();
TiffOutputSet outputSet = metadata.getOutputSet();
TiffOutputDirectory exif = outputSet.getOrCreateExifDirectory();

exif.add(MicrosoftTagConstants.EXIF_TAG_XPAUTHOR, "TEST_AUTHOR");
exif.add(MicrosoftTagConstants.EXIF_TAG_XPCOMMENT, "TEST_COMMENT");
exif.add(MicrosoftTagConstants.EXIF_TAG_XPSUBJECT, "TEST_SUBJECT");
exif.add(MicrosoftTagConstants.EXIF_TAG_XPTITLE, "TEST_TITLE");
exif.add(MicrosoftTagConstants.EXIF_TAG_XPKEYWORDS, "TEST_KEYWORD"); 

FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(new File(JPG_PATH + "\\IMGP5996_empty-2.jpg"));
rewriter.updateExifMetadataLossy(jpgFile, fos, outputSet);
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/dragon66/icafe) is an easy to use library to insert IPTC into both JPEG and TIFF.

Answer (score 0):

I think at this moment, it is not possible to write (with commons imaging) IPTC metadata to a jpg file:
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/todo.html

Answer (score 0):

It would be straightforward, but not trivial, to do this on your own. You would need to rewrite the EXIF APPn Market, but this could be down without modifying the rest of the compressed data stream. You would need to read the EXIF standard to understand how the metadata tags are encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your reply
I have fond a solution with iim4j:
http://iim4j.sourceforge.net/

Good library but poor documenation

Comment: IIM4j was moved from sourceforge to github: https://github.com/vnesek/nmote-iim4j and is available through maven central. Docs were improved a bit... if you need some help with it let me know.